# With Bootstrap 4 Stacked Fixed-Top Navbars, How Do We Keep Dropdowns In Front?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

On a Bootstrap 4 page, I am trying to have a pair of fixed-top navbars, with an `<iframe>` below them filling up the remaining space. It is working well, except for one problem: dropdowns in the upper navbar appear underneath the lower navbar.

[This page](https://commonsware.com/misc/dropdown-issue) reproduces the problem. Here are the results when viewed in Firefox 63 and Chromium 70:

[image: Dropdown Under Lower Navbar]

(please forgive the dark-text-on-dark-navbar for the "Stuff Goes Here" bit)

I am guessing that I need to make some `zindex` adjustments or some such, but I am uncertain why that is needed (shouldn't both navbars be at the same Z index already?) and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a z-index for the class `.fixed-top-2` and instead of using `margin-top` you can use top.

```
.fixed-top-2 {
    /* margin-top: 62px; */
    top: 62px;
    z-index: 90;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a z-index on `fixed-top-2`..

```
.fixed-top-2 {
    z-index: 99;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/9mGKiDSFJ3